How to print sprite in assembly language 8086?
I am trying to print a sprite in assembly language 8086. I have written the code but it does not display anything.
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    sprite DB 00h,00h,00h,00h,00h,00h,00h,00h,0Fh,00h,00h,00h,00h,00h,00h     ;  0
        DB 0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,00h,00h,00h,00h,00h,0Fh,0Fh,0Fh,07h,00h,00h,00h     ;  1
        DB 00h,0Fh,0Fh,07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,00h,00h,0Fh,07h,07h,07h,07h     ;  2
        DB 00h,00h,00h,0Fh,0Fh,07h,07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,00h,0Fh,0Fh,07h     ;  3
        DB 07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,00h,0Fh,0Fh,07h,07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,00h     ;  4
        DB 0Fh,0Fh,07h,07h,08h,08h,00h,00h,00h,0Fh,0Fh,07h,07h,08h,08h     ;  5
        DB 00h,00h,00h,00h,0Fh,07h,07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,00h,00h,0Fh,07h     ;  6
        DB 07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,00h,07h,07h,0Fh,07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,07h     ;  7
        DB 07h,07h,07h,0Fh,0Fh,07h,00h,00h,07h,07h,00h,07h,07h,07h,0Fh     ;  8
        DB 00h,00h,07h,07h,00h,07h,07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,00h,00h,00h,07h     ;  9
        DB 07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,00h,00h,00h,07h,07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,00h     ; 10
        DB 00h,00h,00h,07h,07h,07h,00h,00h,00h,00h,00h,00h,07h,07h,00h     ; 11
     counter1 db ?
     counter2 db ?
     bullet_pos_x db 10

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, 0 
    mov counter1, 0
    mov counter2, 0

    ; Initialize CX and DX for sprite positioning
    mov cx, 100  ; Set initial X position within the screen (between 0 and 319)
    mov dx, 50   ; Set initial Y position within the screen (between 0 and 199)

    drawOuter6:
        drawInner6:
            mov ah, 0ch         ; Set AH to 0Ch for plot pixel function
            mov al, sprite[si]  ; Load pixel color into AL
            int 10h             ; Plot the pixel
            inc cx              ; Increment column counter
            inc counter2        ; Increment inner loop counter
            inc si              ; Move to next pixel in sprite
            cmp counter2, 9     ; Check inner loop counter
            jl drawInner6       ; Repeat inner loop if less than 9 pixels

        mov counter2, 0         ; Reset inner loop counter
        mov cl, bullet_pos_x    ; Load bullet_pos_x into the low byte of CX
        inc dx                  ; Increment row counter
        inc counter1            ; Increment outer loop counter
        cmp counter1, 20        ; Check outer loop counter
        jl drawOuter6           ; Repeat outer loop if less than 20 rows

    end_print:
        ; Exit to DOS
        mov ax, 4C00h
        int 21h

main endp
end main



I have written the code but it does not display anything.

You don't get to see any output because you forget to setup a graphics mode. Based on your mentioning "(between 0 and 319)" and "(between 0 and 199)" that would have to be the 256-color 320x200 graphics mode 13h. A code like:
mov  ax, 0013h  ; AH=00h BIOS function number, AL=13h Mode number
int  10h

will initialize that particular video mode.

mov cl, bullet_pos_x    ; Load bullet_pos_x into the low byte of CX


Don't you want your sprite to occupy a regular rectangle with a width of 9 pixels and a height of 20 pixels? Using CX=100 on the first line, followed by using CX=10 on the other lines is not going to keep things together! It may be that bullet_pos_x db 10 was intended to read bullet_pos_x db 100. In the below solution I have implemented an even simpler solution: since the inner loop has raised CX by 9, it's a simple matter of subtracting 9 from CX to return to the left side of the sprite.

counter1 db ?
counter2 db ?
bullet_pos_x db 10


Whenever possible, it would be best to avoid using memory-based variables. In your program you still have 3 unused registers (BX, DI, and BP). In the below code I have placed the inner counter in BP and the outer counter in DI. I have also set BH=0 because normally BIOS expects BH to contain the display page number. I believe emu8086 does not require this however...
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  ax, 0013h       ; AH=00h BIOS function number, AL=13h Mode number
  int  10h

  mov  bh, 0           ; Select display page (some BIOSes require this)
  mov  cx, 100         ; Set initial X position
  mov  dx, 50          ; Set initial Y position
  xor  si, si          ; Better than `mov si, 0` but same function 
  mov  di, 20          ; Outer loop counter
drawOuter6:
  mov  bp, 9           ; Inner loop counter
drawInner6:
  mov  al, sprite[si]  ; Load pixel color into AL
  mov  ah, 0Ch         ; Set AH to 0Ch for plot pixel function
  int  10h             ; Plot the pixel
  inc  cx              ; Increment X
  inc  si              ; Move to next pixel in sprite
  dec  bp              ; Check inner loop counter
  jnz  drawInner6      ; Repeat inner loop if less than 9 pixels
  sub  cx, 9
  inc  dx              ; Increment Y
  dec  di              ; Check outer loop counter
  jnz  drawOuter6      ; Repeat outer loop if less than 20 lines

Give yourself a chance to actually see what is displayed on the screen. You could wait for the user to press any key on the keyboard before returning to DOS. Most of the time resetting the video mode to the standard 16-color 80x25 text mode 03h is what you'll want:
  mov  ah, 00h         ; BIOS.WaitKeystroke
  int  16h
  mov  ax, 0003h       ; AH=00h BIOS function number, AL=03h Mode number
  int  10h
  mov  ax, 4C00h       ; DOS.Terminate
  int  21h

